IndexOutOfRangeException en sucesión de Fibonacci C#
Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar en C# y quiero hacer un código que muestre una secuencia de Fibonacci que se compondrá de tantos elementos como indique el valor del número introducido. El valor debe de estar comprendido entre 7 y 22.
Lo estoy haciendo con arrays y referencias, creo que casi todos los pasos que he realizado están más o menos bien, pero al introducir el número de elementos me da el error

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Índice fuera de los límites de la
matriz.'

en la referencia "secuenciaFibo".
Por cierto, cómo haría para mostrar los resultados de la lista en orden inverso?
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int elementos = numValidado();
        Console.WriteLine("La secuencia de Fibonacci con " + elementos + " elementos");
        int[] arrayFibo = new int[elementos];
        secuenciaFibo(arrayFibo);
        escribirArray(arrayFibo);
        arrayFibo[0] = 0;
        arrayFibo[1] = 1;
    }
    static public void secuenciaFibo(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i - 2];
        }
    }
    static public void escribirArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static public int numValidado()
    {
        int elementos = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserta el número de caracteres que tendrá la secuencia");
            elementos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (elementos < 7 || elementos > 12)
            { Console.WriteLine("El valor introducido no es correcto"); }
        }
        while (elementos < 7||elementos >12);
        return elementos;
    }
}


Hola Anon, bienvenido, si miras bien las siguientes lineas: for( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ ) { array[ i ] = array[ i - 1 ] + array[ i - 2 ];, verás que en la primer iteración, i vale "0" y le pides un dato con: array[ i - 1 ] y otro con array[ i - 2 ], obviamente fuera de los parámetros de array.

El problema es lógico y se encuentra aquí:
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i - 2];
}

Cuando i vale 0 o 1 se intenta acceder a una posición inválida (-1 o -2). Simplemente inicia i en 2 y problema resuelto.
Para mostrar el arreglo en orden inverso algunas posibilidades son:

Reordenar el arreglo. Lo podes hacer con Array.Reverse o el método de Enumerable Reverse:
Array.Reverse(array);
escribirArray(array); 

// ---- O con enumerables -----
foreach (var numero in array.Reverse()){
    Console.WriteLine(número);
}


O comenzar el for por la última posición y terminar por la primera:
for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Console.WriteLine(número);
}




Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo, solucionando ese y otros pequeños errores ya pude completar el código

@Anon, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada: Click en el check del costado, solo tú como creador de la pregunta, tiene acceso a ello. Saludos :D

La pregunta ha sido respondida correctamente por Mateo, yo solo quiero agregar otra forma de resolver Fibonacci
Lo primero es cambiar la función numValidado la cual renombraré como GetNumValidado y agregaré que valide si lo ingresado por consola es o no un número, además de que si cumple el rango
static public int GetNumValidado()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Inserta el número de caracteres que tendrá la secuencia");
        
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int elementos))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El valor introducido no es un número");
        return GetNumValidado();
    }

    if (elementos is < 7 or > 22)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El valor introducido no está fuera de rango");
        return GetNumValidado();
    }

    return elementos;
}

Luego una función generadora de número de Fibonacci, cuyo algoritmo es bastante simple
static IEnumerable<int> Secuencia()
{
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    yield return first;
    yield return second;
    while (true)
    {
        int temp = first;
        first = second;
        second = second + temp;
        yield return second;
    }
}

Esta función nos permite encontrar cualquier cantidad de números de fibonacci.
Luego la podemos usar de esta manera:
var cantidad = GetNumValidado();
var secuencia = Secuencia().Take(cantidad);

foreach (var item in secuencia)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}


var secuenciaReversa = Secuencia().Take(cantidad).Reverse();
foreach (var item in secuenciaReversa)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}


